# Creating folders in My Documents

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm having trouble creating a directory structure in the Windows My Documents directory. I use

```
ExpandEnvironmentStrings(L"%USERPROFILE%\\Documents",dir,MAX_PATH);
```

to get the directory then I create a new Directory in there

```
CreateDirectoryW(dir,NULL)
```

then in there I want to create another directory so in essence i want Documents\foo\bar however when I go to the foo directory via the Library on explorer side bar 'bar' isn't found unless I go to C:\users\xxx\Documents\foo then its there. Also if I go to Libraries\Documents\foo and right click->New->Folder isn't an option.

I was wondering if there is a Security Option to CreateDirectory I'm supposed to use or what I'm doing wrong

Comment: after calling the API, call GetLastError() and check the error code, you'll find the reason

Comment: What version of Windows are you running.  If Windows 7, try right clicking on your executable and "run As Administrator".  This is a factor many time for me in creating file locations.

Comment: The folders are getting created in C:\users\xxx\Documents but when I view the Desktop>Libraries>Documents link foo is there but the subdirectory bar is missing. CreateDirectoryW returns correctly in both instances and I've checked GetLastError and it reports no problem.

Comment: You need to use `CSIDL` or `KNOWNFOLDERID`

Comment: Note that the My Documents folder might not be at `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` anyway.  You should always use the proper functions to look up the actual folder location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a directory tree, you can use [SHCreateDirectoryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The following code works well on my computer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

int main()
{
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS, NULL, 0, path)))
    {
        PathAppend(path, "foo\\bar");
        if (SHCreateDirectoryEx(NULL, path, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
    }
}
```

Notice that this works only on Windows 2000 Professional or higher.

Comment: You mean `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS` I think